# Measure last row height in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to figure out how to measure the last row height in a table for vertical alignment purposes.

I thought something like this could help me :

```latex
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Example & Example\\
\noalign{\unpenalty\unskip\savebox0\lastbox}
\end{tabular}
```

And then I could measure `\box0`. However, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: the boxes aren't there at the point the noalign is evaluated

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you !

Comment: Unless the contents are larger than will fit, the height should be `\arraystretch\ht\strutbox` and the depth should be `\arraystretch\dp\strutbox`.